# Nullpointer exception in servlet but not in normal class

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to run a code which creates a row in mysql database everything works well with normal classes but when I use servlets it throws a nullpointerexception I am unable to understand the reason why this is happening .

The servlet class:

```
package register;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
@WebServlet("/Create")
public class Create extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 183957L;
    static RegisterModifier rm = new RegisterModifier();
public void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) {
    String name = req.getParameter("employee_name");
    String job = req.getParameter("Job");
    String wing = req.getParameter("Wing");
    try {
      RegisterModifier.create(name, job, wing);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The normal class:

```
 package register;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Test {
public static void main (String main[]) throws SQLException
    {
        RegisterModifier.create("James", "Accountant","Right");
    }
    }
```

The Html form code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="backicon.ico">
    <title>Create Employee Data</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="Create">
    <hr>
<input type="text" name = "employee_name"  placeholder="Enter the employee's full name"> 
<br>
<input type="radio" class="Left Wing"  name="Wing">Left Wing
<br>
<input type="radio" value="Right Wing"  name="Wing">Right Wing
<br>
<select name="Job">
    <option value="">choose the job</option>
    <option value="Clerk">Clerk</option>
    <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
    <option value="Cook">Cook</option>
    <option value="Janitor">Janitor</option>
    <option value="Caterer">Caterer</option>
    <option value="Supervisor">Supervisor</option> 
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit">
  </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

The RegisterModifier class:
with all the methods to interact with database

```
    package register;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class RegisterModifier {
static  Connection connection = Connector.getConnection();
public static void main(String args) throws SQLException {
    create("James","Accountant","Right");
}
static PreparedStatement pstm;
public static void create(String name,String job,String wing) throws SQLException {
    pstm = connection.prepareStatement(Query.create);
    pstm.setString(1,name);
    pstm.setString(2,job);
    pstm.setString(3,wing);
    pstm.execute();
    System.out.println("Employee Created Succesfully");
}
public static void updateName(int id,String name) throws SQLException {
pstm = connection.prepareStatement(Query.updateName);
pstm.setString(1,name);
pstm.setInt(2,id);
}
public void updateJob(int id,String job) throws SQLException 
{
 pstm = connection.prepareStatement(Query.updateJob);
pstm.setString(1,job);
pstm.setInt(2, id);

}
public void updateWing(int id ,String wing) throws SQLException 
{   pstm = connection.prepareStatement(Query.updatewing);
    pstm.setString(1,wing);
    pstm.setInt(2, id);
    pstm.execute();

}
public void read() throws SQLException
{
    pstm = connection.prepareStatement(Query.read);
    pstm.execute();
}
public void read(int id) throws SQLException
{
    pstm = connection.prepareStatement(Query.readById);
    pstm.setInt(1, id);
    pstm.execute();
}
public void read(String name) throws SQLException
{
    pstm = connection.prepareStatement(Query.readById);
    pstm.setString(1, name);
    pstm.execute();
}

public void delete(int id)throws SQLException
{
pstm = connection.prepareStatement(Query.delete);
pstm.setInt(1,id);
pstm.execute();
}
}
```

The Query class
The class with all the mysql queries

```
package register;
public class Query
    {
        
        static String create ="insert into Bank_Employees (full_name,job,wing) value(?,?,?)";
        static String updateName = "update Bank_Employees set full_name = ? where id= ?";
        static String updateJob = "update Bank_Employees set job = ? where id= ?";
        static String updatewing = "update Bank_Employees set wing = ? where id= ?";
        static String read = "Select * from Bank_Employees ";
        static String readById = "Select  from Bank_Employees where id = ? ";
        static String readByName = "Select  from Bank_Employees where full_name = ?";
        static String delete = "Delete from Bank_Employees where id = ?";
    
    }
```

Connector class
The class which connects to the database

```
package register;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Connector {
static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
static String Database1="data2";
static String user = "root";
static String password = "Ronitpandey123";
static Connection con;
public static Connection getConnection()
{
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+Database1,user,password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
}
```

The normal test class works well and I can see the table row generated but using the servlet
throws an error 500 internal server error and says that RegisterModifier.connection is null
although it works with normal java class.

This is the error page :

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "register.RegisterModifier.connection" is null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "register.RegisterModifier.connection" is null
    register.RegisterModifier.create(RegisterModifier.java:12)
    register.Create.service(Create.java:16)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.71
```

These are the console logs in eclipse ide:

```
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.71
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jan 9 2023 22:33:01 UTC
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.71.0
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 11
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Users\dkent\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502\jre
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           17.0.7+7
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Eclipse Adoptium
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\dkent\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\servers for java ee jdk 19\apache-tomcat-9.0.71
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\dkent\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\servers for java ee jdk 19\apache-tomcat-9.0.71
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\dkent\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\dkent\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/dkent/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/dkent/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.7.v20230425-1502/jre/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\dkent\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\dkent\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\dkent\eclipse;;.]
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:40 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [595] milliseconds
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.71]
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:40 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [473] milliseconds
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data2
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at register.Connector.getConnection(Connector.java:14)
    at register.RegisterModifier.<clinit>(RegisterModifier.java:6)
    at register.Create.<clinit>(Create.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1067)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Jun 05, 2023 9:24:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [register.Create] in context with path [/BankEmployeeRegister] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "register.RegisterModifier.connection" is null
    at register.RegisterModifier.create(RegisterModifier.java:12)
    at register.Create.service(Create.java:16)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Jun 05, 2023 9:34:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/BankEmployeeRegister] has started
Jun 05, 2023 9:34:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/BankEmployeeRegister] is completed
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data2
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at register.Connector.getConnection(Connector.java:14)
    at register.RegisterModifier.<clinit>(RegisterModifier.java:6)
    at register.Create.<clinit>(Create.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1067)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Jun 05, 2023 9:45:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [register.Create] in context with path [/BankEmployeeRegister] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "register.RegisterModifier.connection" is null
    at register.RegisterModifier.create(RegisterModifier.java:12)
    at register.Create.service(Create.java:16)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Jun 05, 2023 9:46:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [register.Create] in context with path [/BankEmployeeRegister] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "register.RegisterModifier.connection" is null
    at register.RegisterModifier.create(RegisterModifier.java:12)
    at register.Create.service(Create.java:16)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Something seems very odd it works well with normal java class  but using servlets throws null pointes exception

Comment: `No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data2`: the driver for your database is not available when running in tomcat

Comment: Make sure the jdbc driver class is added to tomcat's classpath

Comment: @ScaryWombat Can you please tell how to do so

Comment: No, google it yourself.  That is how you learn.

Comment: @OlafKock So how can I fix this issue

Comment: @ScaryWombat I was unable to find any solution online that's why I chose to post on Stack Overflow please help

Answer (score 1):

The way you obtain a database connection in a servlet is very different to the way you do it with a regular Java class (also referred to as [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object)).

1. Copy [MySQL JDBC driver JAR file](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j) to `lib` subdirectory of [Apache] Tomcat installation.
2. Add file `context.xml` to `META-INF` folder in WAR file. File contents as follows. Note that you can replace *db* with whatever you like, e.g. *jdbc/ipsum*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/db"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data2"
              username="root"
              password="Ronitpandey123"
              maxTotal="20"
              maxIdle="10"
              maxWaitMillis="-1"/>
</Context>
```

3. Add following [XML] element to file `web.xml` (in WAR file). Note that `res-ref-name` matches [`Resource`] `name` in file `context.xml`, above.

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/db</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

4. In code of servlet (i.e. class `Create`), use following code to obtain database connection.

```java
javax.naming.Context ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
javax.naming.Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/db");
java.sql.Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: is backend development really so boring